# Oracle Applications - programmatically manipulate form data

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

Oracle applications 11.5.7 with Forms Server 6 - is there any way to programmatically send data from the client to the server, as if they were coming from the client forms?

This is an old version but am stuck with it for now.

I guess this is an Oracle internal protocol which details how a client JVM sends data across the network to the forms server to get it to accept user input. But can I simulate this, at least for simple data input - my goal would be to get mass data input done in a programmatic fashion rather than having to use either the Oracle forms or get an Oracle specialist to do a custom-loader for me, which is likely to be exorbitantly expensive.

I looked already at "generic" input loaders for BOMs, routings, costs etc, such as apps4more.com, but they won't support 11.5.7. The only one I found so far which would support 11.5.7 was exorbitantly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Forms Playback](http://www.dataload.com/help/recplay/setup.htm)?

You can record Forms actions to file and playback it later. It can be useful if you just need to redo the same activity on diffrent instances. File is plaintext, but unfortunatly format is quite difficult and it is not easy to generate it by means other than record...